# Dynamically change page size in dir-paginate in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using dir-paginate in angularjs. My question is that should i set pagesize dynamically? Means if my screen resolutions are like 1280×800, 1440×900, 1680×1050, 1920×1200 and 2560×1600 then pagesize should change accordingly.

```
<tr dir-paginate="ClientAppr in filteredPhones = ( AllClientApprDtls | filter:search:strict ) | itemsPerPage:pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
    <td class= "col-md-2">{{ClientAppr.persFullName}}</td>
    <td class= "col-md-2"> {{ClientAppr.clientName}} </td>
    <td class= "col-md-1"> {{ClientAppr.activeType}} </td>
    <td class= "col-md-2"> {{ClientAppr.persOffEmail}} </td>
    <td class= "col-md-2"> {{ClientAppr.clientRepTypeDesc}} </td>
</tr>
```

In this examle itemsPerPage = pageSize

I declaired pagesize = 8 then it will display 8 items per page.

Comment: What does pagination of records have to do with the size of your page, specifically?  Is there some kind of specific design which mandates it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use . **max-size** conditionally.. **[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/eEE0UvUMyNxKf3Ivv8FS?p=preview)** (optional, default = 9) Specify a maximum number of pagination links to display. The default is 9, and the minimum is 5 (setting a lower value than 5 will not have an effect).

so your pagination html will be

```
<div class="paginationCont">
    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="size" boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="templates/pagination_ctrls.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

and script

```
var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    if(screenWidth < 768){
        $scope.size=5;
    } else if (screenWidth >= 768 && screenWidth < 992){
        $scope.size=6;
    }else if (screenWidth >= 991 && screenWidth < 1200){
        $scope.size=7;
    }else if (screenWidth >= 1200){
        $scope.size=8;
    }
```

[image]